# Publicar proyecto Blazor WASM .Net 7 con Asp.Core hosted en Microsoft Azure

Tags: asp.net, app, azure, blazor, wasm

Soy novato en Blazor, tengo un problema de publicar mi proyecto blazor web assembly en Azure. Estoy trabajando con .NET 7 con asp.core hosted.  Soy nuevo en blazor utilizo Radzen como biblioteca de componentes.

Tengo dos partie de Servidor y cliente.
Server:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>BlazorApp3.Server-3ca63985-e8d6-4570-89df-eb3c14525c26</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="7.0.16" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\BlazorApp3.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\BlazorApp3.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="7.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.16" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

He visto que Azure App Web Static no soporta él framework.net 7 como en este artículo

https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1016

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tampoco el proyecto no compila con GitHub Actions. Siempre tengo problemas en archivo main.yml.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede ayudarme como puedo publicar un proyecto Blazor web assembly .net7 con ASP. Core Hosted en Azure?